# Mail Filtering - MS Exchange

Tags: exchange, email, filter

I am on MS Exchange in my office and daily I receive about 500 bugzilla mails addressed to an ilist. I wanted to filter them out. Planning to setup a linux mail server to receive the mails and filter the bugzilla mails there. Any idea how to setup this.

Comment: Does Excahnge (server side) not have any sort or decent user-level (controlled) content filtering? Like mail lists, TO/CC regex, From regex, LIST-ID, etc? This would seem like a must for any half way decent MDA. Tweeks

Comment: @user218674 As it happens, Exchange does have those for server-defined lists. Outlook, the preferred client for Exchange, has a host of client-defined filters that can be used.

Answer (score 3):

That seems like a large amount of overkill. Firstly, if you don't want them, can you unsubscribe from the list? If not, why not just set up an Outlook rule to either delete these emails, or move them to another folder?